# Analogue of Margulis height function in non lattice subgroups

Tags: lie-groups, ds.dynamical-systems

I have been reading this paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11854-017-0033-4 on *singular system of linear forms and non escape of mass in homogeneous spaces* $G/\Gamma$ where $ G=SL(m+n,\mathbb{R})$ and $\Gamma=SL(m+n,\mathbb{Z})$. Their approach heavily relies on Margulis height function constructed suitably to track the trajectories outside compact sets or near cuspidial ends.

I am just curious if height function analogue anything is available in the literature for non Lattice subgroups also. Because for Lattices one has Mahler compactness result so the height function can be constructed suitably satisfying our need. But is there anything similar could be done for non *Lattice subgroups* ? Any insight would be very beneficial for understanding.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by non lattice subgroups. Margulis functions control height of elements in homogeneous spaces when you have “local expansion” of your averaging operator. There are analogues of Mahler’s compactness in other settings (Mumford’s theorem and others), the issue is usually the construction of the Margulis function and then actually proving local expansion, namely the key lemma of Eskin-Margulis.

Now with that in mind, what do you mean by non lattice subgroups here?

Comment: Non lattice means discrete subgroups say in $Sln(\mathbb{R})$ but not of finite volume. Say for example in higher rank Kleiner or Anosov subgroups.

Comment: How would you characterize escape to to a cusp in such a situation by an algebraic statement?

Comment: I am not sure what I meant to say e.g for lattices it's discrete with finite covolume; I am asking about some discrete subgroup but say with infinite covolume; the trajectories would ventures the cusps right? Since now these are not finitely many can we make sense of these height function here ?

Comment: I am still not following. One can just measure divergence from an arbitrary point say in the thick part, just as one chooses a base point for the PS measure. I don’t see the relation to Margulis functions here. note that the critical fact in all applications is that the Margulis function majroizes all the Euclidean minima, which can in turn control divergence by Mahler’s. So I suspect you are actually something else without any relation to Margulis inequalities.